# assign columns value on rowdatabound in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am facing a problem in grid view, basically what i am trying to achieve is below:
I have a grid view in which my first column is a link button, i have to put a condition where value from my 2nd column is taken and is input to a c# method for poulating a value which i need to assign into my first column.

I am trying below code however when i view my grid its showing 1st columns value as blank.
Aspx page:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FileName" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"> 
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:LinkButton ID="btn"  runat="server" CommandName="Click"/>
</ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>
```

aspx.cs

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
int EmpiD = Int32.Parse(e.Row.Cells[2].Text);
DataSet EmpIDDs = GetEMP.getValue(EmpiD);
DataRow EmpRow = EmpIDDs.Tables[0].Rows[0];
e.Row.Cells[0].Text = EmpRow[3].ToString();
}
```

Please help me if you have any solution

Comment: -1 _however its not working_ is not a valid description of what's going wrong.

Comment: 'Cells[2]' That's the third column, not the second. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Grid is not displaying any value in my first column when i use above code

Comment: Also, what event is the above code bound to, databound?

Comment: Does all **e.Row.Cells[2].Text** contains integer values??

Comment: huMpty duMpty yes they are integers...

Comment: You say they are integers - Sorry to question you but do you _expect_ them to be integers or does the debugger show they _are_ integers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Grid is not displaying any value in my first column when i use above
>   code

You say that the `LinkButton`  is in the first `TemplateField`, then you cannot set the `Text` property of the cell. You need to use `FindControl` to get a reference to your `LinkButton`.

```
LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("btn");
int EmpiD = Int32.Parse(e.Row.Cells[2].Text);
DataSet EmpIDDs = GetEMP.getValue(EmpiD);
DataRow EmpRow = EmpIDDs.Tables[0].Rows[0];
btn.Text = EmpRow[3].ToString();
```

Assuming that the rest of your code is correct, for example that the third column is a `BoundField` and contains an integer so that `e.Row.Cells[2]`  works.

I'm not sure if you're familiar with the debugger.

Debugging-Tutorial: http://www.dotnetperls.com/debugging

Comment: Thanks it worked.....it was just a silly thing that i was doing incorrectly..thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

1st, I would get the data item that you have bound, not the text of the cell.

2nd, You must use find control and set the text property of the LinkButton not the text of the cell.

```
if (args.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
YourObject dataObj = args.Row.DataItem as YourObj;
LinkButton but = args.Row.FindControl("linkButtonId") as LinkBUtton;
if(but != null)
{
but.Text = dataObj.SomePropertyYouWantToUse;
}
}
```